# What seems to be wrong with my code in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
....
path('My-History/', accounts.views.History, name='MyHistory'),
path('Complaint/<int:id>/edit', accounts.views.EditComplaint.as_view(), name='Complaint')
]
```

views.py:

```
def History(request):
  complaint_data = Complaint.objects.filter(user=request.user) 
  context = { 'complaint':complaint_data }
  return render(request, 'myHistory.html', context)

class EditComplaint(UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
   model = Complaint
   fields = ('info', 'reportnumber', 'eventdate', 'event_type', 'device_problem', 
  'manufacturer', 'product_code', 'brand_name', 'exemption', 'patient_problem', 'event_text', 
  'document') 

   def form_valid(self, request):
       complaint = request.user.complaint
       form = ComplaintForm(instance=complaint)
       if request.method == 'POST':
          form = ComplaintForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=complaint)
          if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
       context = {'form': form}
       return render(request, 'newcomplaint.html', context)

   def test_func(self):
       complain = self.get_object()

       if self.request.user == complain.user:
           return True
       raise Http404(_('This complain does not exist'))
```

models.py:

```
class Complaint(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)
   id = models.AutoField(blank=False, primary_key=True)
   reportnumber = models.CharField(max_length=500 ,null = True, blank= False)
   eventdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
   event_type = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   device_problem = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   product_code = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   brand_name = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
   exemption = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   patient_problem = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
   event_text = models.TextField(null=True, blank= True)
   document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/documents', blank=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.reportnumber
```

template for my-history:

```
<div class="col-lg middle middle-complaint-con">
        <i class="fas fa-folder-open fa-4x comp-folder-icon"></i>
        <h1 class="all-comp">My Complaints</h1>
        <p class="all-comp-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

        {%for c in complaint %}
        <a href="{% url 'Complaint' complaint.id %}" style="color:black;">
            <div class="container comp-con-{{forloop.counter0}}">
                <p style="color: #D37A19; margin-left: -130px; margin-top: -5px;">Report number:</p>
                <p class="history-level-1">{{c.reportnumber}}</p>
                <p class="comp-title-1">{{c.event_type}}</p>
                <p class="comp-sub-1">{{c.event_text}}</p>
            </div>
        </a> {%endfor%}
    </div>
```

note: When I remove "{% url 'Complaint' complaint.id %}" the my history page shows up but then I can't go to the detail page for the individual complaint. If I keep this url in then this page shows up:

[image]

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url "complaint" is set as to recieve an argument... But as the error traceback says, There is no argument that is being passed into the complaint url...

Change this and try ,

This

```
{%for c in complaint %}
        <a href="{% url 'Complaint' complaint.id %}" style="color:black;">
```

into

```
{%for c in complaint %}
        <a href="{% url 'Complaint' c.id %}" style="color:black;">
```

Since you are iterating through the complaint query object with 'c', you have to access each id by **c.id**

Comment: Oh! that makes sense! yeah i'll try and let you know